# Inserting div and span in php code

Tags: php, html

I am trying to get my webshops ratings to output to google with microdata. But i am not so good with php coding.

I need to place 1 div and 2 span´s into the code.

Here is the original working code :

```
if ($avgratings > 0) {
        $final_avgreview_data = '<img src="'.REDSHOP_ADMIN_IMAGES_ABSPATH.'star_rating/'.$avgratings.'.gif" />';
        $final_avgreview_data .= JText::_('COM_REDSHOP_RATING' )." ".$avgratings." ".JText::_(' ' );
        $final_avgreview_data .= JText::_('COM_REDSHOP_AVG_RATINGS_1' )." ".$totalreviews." ".JText::_('COM_REDSHOP_AVG_RATINGS_2' );
    }
    return $final_avgreview_data;
}
```

Here is have just dumped the div and span´s into the code, but it need to be swapped correctly to work.

```
if ($avgratings > 0) {
        <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
        $final_avgreview_data = '<img src="'.REDSHOP_ADMIN_IMAGES_ABSPATH.'star_rating/'.$avgratings.'.gif" />';
        $final_avgreview_data .= JText::_('COM_REDSHOP_RATING' )." <span itemprop="ratingValue"> ".$avgratings." </span> ".JText::_(' ' );
        $final_avgreview_data .= JText::_('COM_REDSHOP_AVG_RATINGS_1' )." <span itemprop="reviewCount"> ".$totalreviews." </span> ".JText::_('COM_REDSHOP_AVG_RATINGS_2' );
        </div>
    }
```

I Hope someone can help me :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will add the div and spans around the ratings:

```
if ($avgratings > 0) {
    $final_avgreview_data = '<div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">';
    $final_avgreview_data .= '<img src="'.REDSHOP_ADMIN_IMAGES_ABSPATH.'star_rating/'.$avgratings.'.gif" />';
    $final_avgreview_data .= JText::_('COM_REDSHOP_RATING' ).' <span itemprop="ratingValue"> '.$avgratings.' </span> '.JText::_(' ' );
    $final_avgreview_data .= JText::_('COM_REDSHOP_AVG_RATINGS_1' ).' <span itemprop="reviewCount"> '.$totalreviews.' </span> '.JText::_('COM_REDSHOP_AVG_RATINGS_2' );
    $final_avgreview_data .= '</div>';
}
```

Comment: When i replace the code with this my site gets a 500 server error.

Comment: Sorry. I had copied the code and replace the old, but also with return $final_avgreview_data;   so that where missing.
It is working now. Thank you.